# Unable to start programs installed by Fink in Mac

Tags: mac

I run

```
fink install meld
```

However, the command `meld` cannot be found when I run

```
meld
```

**How can you run apps installed by Fink in Mac?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at question 8.4 on the Fink F.A.Q (http://www.finkproject.org/faq/usage-general.php):

Q8.4: I can't run any of my Fink-installed applications using the Applications menu in Apple X11.

A: Apple X11 doesn't keep track of the Fink environment settings, which means that the Applications menu doesn't have the PATH set correctly to find your Fink applications. The solution is to preface the name of a Fink-installed application with

source /sw/bin/init.sh ;

The site gives examples of how to add your new application to the X11 Path.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you can add that line:

```
source /sw/bin/init.sh
```

to the .bashrc file in your $HOME directory, log out and log back in and then Fink commands will all work w/o having to type that as a prefix each time.